# Java Application for handling records(CRUD)

Tags: java, xml

I am new to JavaEE and am faced with a tight situation here.

I have to develop a Java application for (CRUD) handling records and saving and loading an XML concerning that record. Obviously, I won't be asking you to do this for me. What I would be asking you is to give me some hints/pointer. Initially I thought JAXB would be enough for this but after putting a lot of time learning it and implementing the program I realized that it just can create the XML and read it but for update, delete I would have to do something else. Even if it wasn't for update and delete features requirement for my project I would still think that by just using JAXB is not a good implementation.

I was wondering if "REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey" should do the trick for me. ?

Comment: Do you want the data persisted as XML, or just the interactions to be in XML?  Here is a link to a `JAX-RS` application where `JAXB` is leveraged for the XML messages and the persistence is done to a relational database leveraging `JPA`:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read my question. I did not completely undertsood your answer but would tell you what exactly i am planning to make a java application which takes input from command line to create a xml file then one can update the xml file with putting/editing records, read the xml file and delete a entry in the xml file.

Answer (score 1):

JAX-RS isn't really going to help you for this.  Much as JAX-B is for binding and unbinding XML to Java, JAX-RS is about building and consuming RESTful services.  Neither really deals with data persistence.

What you need to look at is an XML database, such as [BaseX](http://basex.org/), which allows you to use [XQuery](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery) to query and manipulate your XML.